# Fails to style with styleUrls in Angular component's scss file

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, angular-components

I selected the scss option on a new Ionic Angular app. It's html container holds three tab pages. The scss stylesheet in the container component controls the styles for all pages. The global.sccs only contains imports, no styling and doesn't import the container's scss.. The container component implements OnInit.The stylesheets in the 3 tab page components are created empty.

I cannot change the style of any of the 3 tab pages by adding styles to their stylesheets. It continues to use the container's stylesheet. The selector for the style is in the container's html:

explore-container.component.html

```
<div id="container">
  <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
  ...
</div>
```

The explore-container.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-explore-container',
  templateUrl: './explore-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./explore-container.component.scss'],
})
export class ExploreContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

The tab page html uses the selector for the container component:

tab1.page.html

...

```
  <app-explore-container name="Tab 1 page"></app-explore-container>
</ion-content>
```

The tab1.page.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor() {}

}
```

I have reviewed the docs about external stylesheets and encapsulation but I'm still lost. Why can't I just add a style to the scss in the tab page's own presently empty scss file? Eg., why doesn't inserting styles into the page component's scss:

tab1.page.scss

```
 #container strong {
 font-size: 40px;
```

}

override this in the explore-container.component.scss?

```
 #container strong {
 font-size: 20px;
```

}

Am I missing an import somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: You’re actually trying to style the parent from the child. This won’t just work as styles are by default encapsulated. If you want to make this work you have multiple options, one is to add viewEncapsulation.None to your child components. An other would be to use ::ng-deep..

Comment: If I use viewEncapsulation.None on each of the 3 tab pages it seems logical I would then need to use IDs' on elements with the same property <div id="sumpn"><strong>blah blah</strong>? I tried encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, on the component decorator in both the tab1.page.ts and explore-contain.component.ts with no luck in either direction. If I have been trying to style from the child to the parent would ::ngdeep be relevant since the documentation says it forces the style down through all of the "children"?

Comment: Also this from Angular reference - "The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools."

Comment: Yes - ::ng-deep has been deprecated for a few years now :-) basically what happens if you encapsulate none is that the styles are moved to global styles which should work fine. However, it might be better to make a consistent choice and style everything globally

Comment: Thanks. I think maybe I need to learn how to use the developer tools a little better. The visualization of the container holding three items lead me to think of the container is the parent rather than having three parents with the container as the child. I still don't understand why the ViewEncapsulation.None method isn't working as expected.